How to consecutively call asynchronous functions in Javascript
everyone, in my school, i have a project that i code javascript to automated test a page
i use webdriver to text
but i have a error : TypeError: loginPageInstance.inputUsername(...).inputPassword is not a function
at Context. (D:\PVD_HOCTAP\Back End\Javascript\Automated_Testing_demo\test\pageObject2\testScript/testLogin.js:18:67)
I still don't know how to fix it. I hope everyone will help me. Sorry for my poor English, I hope everyone will forgive meenter image description hereenter image description here
I want my testcase must be setValue username and password before click

post code, not pretty pictures of code

sorry that is the first time that i use stackoverflow to ask a question. I won't make that mistake next time

Since each of your functions return promises, you will need to await each one before you can call the next function. This make function chaining very cumbersome:
const loginPageInstance = new loginPage();
await (
  await (
    await loginPageInstance.inputUsername(loginData.correctCredentials.username)
  ).inputPassword(loginData.correctCredentials.password)
).clickOnLoginBtn();

Since the promise resolves to the same instance you started with, i would instead recommend doing it like this:
await loginPageInstance.inputUsername(loginData.correctCredentials.username)
await loginPageInstance.inputPassword(loginData.correctCredentials.password)
await loginPageInstance.clickOnLoginBtn();

